# How to display a message only on logging in the webpage in PHP?

Tags: php, session

I have a website in PHP, and I want that when user logs in to his profile he sees a message on the Dashboard like Welcome "". Now here the twist is that I want this message to be displayed only when user has just logged in not everytime with the continued session.

What could be done in this case? please help...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the variable in the session. Have a condition on your dashboard page that looks something like:

```
<?php 
if( isset($_SESSION['welcome_message']) )
{
    echo $_SESSION['welcome_message']; 
    unset($_SESSION['welcome_message']);
}
?>
```

So then it will not be displayed on subsequent page hits.

This is often referred to as a 'flash' message.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a flag in the `$_SESSION` array.

```
    <?php
    if (!isset($_SESSION['display_greeting'])){
        echo "Hello " . $name;
        $_SESSION['display_greeting']=1;
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I will presume you only want this message to be shown once ever, e.g. on their first log in, you need to:

1. If `message_displayed` in the database is false, if it is then display the message
2. Set `message_displayed` in the database against the user to true

Now an subsequent log ins it will be set in the database. Doing it only in the session will mean it may get shown again if they remove their cookies or log in from another machine.

***Edit:***

On second thoughts this isn't sustainable. Really you need a notifications system.

1. A notification is generated in a table of its own with a user id
2. When a user logs in the notifications table is checked
3. If a notification exists then it is displayed and marked as read or deleted

This way you can have many notifications shown just once rather than relying on a single database column in the user table. Also you can have different triggers for the notifications, e.g. it gets shown once and its deleted or it only gets deleted when  specific action has taken place for example Accepting/Rejecting a Friend Request.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common feature of frameworks.  The idea is you store a message in a session, then after it is displayed, you remove it.  A basic example would me:

```
session_start()
$_SESSION['message'] = "thanks for logging in";
header('Location: index.php');
```

then in your index.

```
if ($_SESSION['message'])
{
    echo $_SESSION['message'];
    unset($_SESSION['message'];
}
```

These are known as flash messages, and implementations already exist.  Check out: https://github.com/jimmiw/php-flash-message

Answer (score 0):

hi create a log_report(or what ever name) table in which you enter the time when user logins but before enter put that time into session and compare time with your existing records, if that record is not existing display the message otherwise not. And compare that session time all time whenever page loads. if existing dont show otherwise show....